# Dizer que um vernáculo é um vernáculo, é errado?

Tags: sinônimos

Tudo bem, soa redundante! Mas isso não quer dizer que não é um recurso retórico válido, certo ?

Comment: Raphael, um vernáculo é definitivamente um vernáculo, e um homem é um homem, e um bicho é um bicho. Mas qual é exatamente a tua dúvida? Em certos contextos, redundâncias desse tipo podem ser usadas com bom efeito.

Comment: Oi Raphael, bem-vindo ao Portuguese SE. Você pode esclarecer qual tua dúvida, se é por exemplo gramatical, ou sobre um recurso de retórica, etc.?

Comment: Obrigado @stafusa, seria mais como recurso retórico.

Comment: E @Jacinto, muito bom o seu ponto. A dúvida é no sentido redundante da coisa,.  O que você quis dizer com (...) redundâncias ..   _podem ser usadas com bom efeito ?_

Comment: Legal, Raphael, era o que eu tinha imaginado, mas nem todos entenderam (e inclusive já tinham votado para fechar a questão), então eu editei sua pergunta, baseado no teu comentário, tentando deixá-la mais clara. É só uma sugestão minha - você pode reverter minha edição e/ou editar a postagem você mesmo, se preferir.

Comment: Raphael, por exemplo, há o ditado "um homem é um homem, um bicho é um bicho (corta-se o rabo, fica rabicho)", que quer dizer que um homem é corajoso, capaz... enfim, é um homem, mais que um bicho. Ou se eu te perguntar, "o que é 'vernáculo'? ", e tu não estiveres para me explicar, podes dizer "vernáculo é vernáculo (consulta um dicionário)". Agora, eu não faço ideia que é que tu queres dizer com "um vernáculo é um vernáculo", em que contexto é que irias usar isso, e para que efeito.

Comment: @Jacinto No sentido de "o significado é óbvio / consulte um dicionário", vejo tanto "vernáculo é vernáculo" quanto "um vernáculo é um vernáculo" como possibilidades aceitáveis.

Comment: @stafusa, não digo que não seja. Precisava de ver o contexto. Vêm-me mais naturalmente à cabeça exemplos com ***o** vernáculo* do que com ***um** vernáculo*.

Comment: Votei para reabrir. Eu gostaria de ver mais contexto. Como está é muito abstrata, mas é respondível.

Comment: Agradeço a vocês acima que tentaram dialogar com a minha pergunta. Foi minha primeira pergunta aqui e vou buscar me fazer mais claro nas próximas. O contexto, afinal, é impreciso até pra mim. Essa é uma dúvida antiga que resolvi retomar pela ocasião [ a da chegada a esse fórum]. A resposta de todos me fez muito sentido, sobretudo a do @stafusa. Grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embora frases como esta, isoladas, possam ser tautologias, seu uso como recurso de retórica é bem estabelecido. Um exemplo é o [conhecido](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-da-expressao-uma-coisa-e-uma-coisa/16511) ditado popular

> Uma coisa é uma coisa, outra coisa é outra coisa.

que é usado para colocar de modo enfático que "são coisas diferentes", similarmente a outra expressão [comum](https://www.dicionariopopular.com/trocar-alhos-por-bugalhos/): "misturar alhos e bugalhos" (*mix oranges and apples*). Outra expressão próxima é

> Cada um, cada um.

título de uma [música](https://www.letras.mus.br/analise/cada-um-cada-um/), e que enfatiza que as pessoas são diferentes entre si - diferenças que devem ser respeitadas - embora possa também ter o significado de que as pessoas devem resolver seus próprios problemas (*to each their own*).

E uma frase como a do título, "um vernáculo é um vernáculo", costuma ser usada para ressaltar a identidade do sujeito e pode conferir uma série de ênfases diferentes, por exemplo:

- não foge à sua natureza: [um leão é um leão](https://books.google.de/books?id=hgOsgkcBnIYC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22um+le%C3%A3o+%C3%A9+um+le%C3%A3o%22&source=bl&ots=vNqDBYYcFk&sig=ACfU3U0bRBOFaA8GFuZrVMA2_BKD6PorWg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXpPHmpL7kAhWSyKQKHcL8ABQQ6AEwDXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22um%20le%C3%A3o%20%C3%A9%20um%20le%C3%A3o%22&f=false) (e não deixa de caçar);
- pertence exclusivamente a uma categoria: [uma cobra é uma cobra](https://objetivismo.com.br/artigo/quais-sao-os-problemas-da-filosofia-de-ayn-rand) (e nada mais);
- pertence sem restrições: [um judeu é um judeu](https://identidadeisraelita.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/projeto-de-lei-poderia-redefinir-quem-e-um-judeu-em-israel-proposed-bill-could-redefine-who-is-a-jew-in-israel/) (e não importa a natureza da conversão);

ou ainda para indicar que o significado é óbvio: "O que é um vernáculo? -- Um vernáculo é um vernáculo, oras!".

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado @stafusa.